# Signing requests in Python for OAuth

Tags: python, oauth, signature

currently I'm interfacing the Twitter API using the OAuth protocol and writing the code in Python. As most of the users out there, I think the toughest part of the specs is dealing with signatures.

After wandering around the web in search for a solution, I decided to go for my custom code, so as to have a better understanding of what is going on.

For the sake of other users, I'm posting here a very simple and short implementation of the SHA1 signature specs in Python:

```
import hmac

from hashlib import sha1
from urllib import quote, urlencode
from base64 import b64encode
from urlparse import urlparse

def sign_request_sha1(url,method,data,secret=""):
  pu = urlparse(urlparse(url).geturl())

  normUrl = "%s://%s%s%s" % (
      pu.scheme,
      pu.hostname,
      "" if not pu.port or {"http":80,"https":443}[pu.scheme] == pu.port else ":%d" % pu.port,
      pu.path,
                            )

  names = data.keys()
  names.sort()

  sig = "%s&%s&%s" % (
          method.upper(),
          quote(normUrl,''),
          quote("&".join(["%s=%s" % (k,quote(data[k].encode('utf-8'),'')) for k in names]),''),
                     )

  key = "%s&%s" % (quote(CONSUMER_SECRET.encode('utf-8'),''),secret)

  return b64encode(hmac.new(key,sig,sha1).digest())
```

The input parameters to the function are:

- url: the url you are going to call for the specific OAuth request.
- method: this must be "GET" or "POST" depending on how you're going to issue your request.
- data: a dictionary containing all the parameters of the requests, including any custom argument but excluding the "oauth_signature" one (for obvious reasons).
- secret: a secret token you received in the initial phase of the protocol.

I tested it with Twitter and it seems to work but I'd like to receive some comments about mistakes, improvements and so on.

Lastly, here you find a piece of code calling the code for the initial "request token" phase:

```
from random import getrandbits
from base64 import b64encode
from time import time

def twitter_request_token(req,callback,errback):
  req_url="http://twitter.com:80/oauth/request_token"

  data = { \
    "oauth_consumer_key" : CONSUMER_KEY,
    "oauth_nonce" : b64encode("%0x" % getrandbits(256))[:32],
    "oauth_timestamp" : str(int(time())),
    "oauth_signature_method" : "HMAC-SHA1",
    "oauth_version" : "1.0",
    "oauth_callback" : "http://localhost:8080/",
         }

  data["oauth_signature"] = sign_request_sha1(req_url,"GET",data)
```

Thank you.

Comment: could you explain what's the point of `normURL` exercise?

Comment: The specs are very strict on what must be in the URL used to create the signature.

Hence, starting from the passed url which may not be compliant with the specs (for example, due to some chars being uppercase), the function generate a new URL.

The first line takes advantage of the urlparse module to obtain a first sanitization of the URL: here I'm not sure whether the only effect is to make all chars lowercase.

In the string interpolation it uses the URL elements to form the new URL, omitting the port when it's the default one for the scheme in use (80 for http and 443 for https).

Comment: So you're writing this as an alternative to the code at oauth.googlecode.com?

Comment: Not quite. I'm just starting to use OAuth and wanted to have a more in-depth view of what was happening. Anyhow, even if the oauth python lib does its job, I've found it rather complex for the purpose of just learning the protocol machinery: that's the reason why I posted this snippet. Currently I don't know whether in my project I'll switch to the oauth lib or not but it's true that I find it a bit too involved, at least for my purpose and my personal view of Python programming.

Comment: Note that the variables CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET must be either hard-coded into this snippet before use, or must be defined in the calling environment- this isn't particularly pythonic. Also, the callback and errback parameters are not used in  `twitter_request_token()`. That being said, I found this useful for understanding what's going on behind the scenes in creating an oauth signature, and could be expanded/unpacked as a great tutorial!

Answer (score 2):

My knee-jerk reaction to this is [If You're Typing The Letters A-E-S Into Your Code, You're Doing It Wrong](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2009/7/22/if-youre-typing-the-letters-a-e-s-into-your-code-youre-doing.html).  Or, as redditor [khafra recently reminded us of the Sicilian's version](http://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/attt2/dont_hash_secrets/c0jdilj):

> Haha.. you fool! You fell victim to one of the classic blunders. The most famous is: Never get involved in a land war in Asia. But only slightly less famous is this: Never attempt to roll your own crypto when there's a well-tested library that'll do it better!

I mean, I get it.  The first time I looked at it, [oauth.py](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/python/oauth/oauth.py) didn't impress me either.  There's been a lot of work on it since and it's looking better, but there still appear to be no tests, so I don't know.  Anyway, tests or no tests, it's been reviewed and used by more people than your code has.

But that's just me being uptight on the subject of crypto code reuse and doesn't really help you in figuring out the protocol machinery.  It looks okay to me, but I haven't had my head in the OAuth spec too much lately.

Just use some more lines for that `pu.port` business; having a conditional `if` expression, an `or` expression, and the `{}[]` construct all in one line is *really* hard to read.

If you really want code review by people who are familiar with the protocol, you're probably better off asking [the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/oauth/).  And if you can offer them an alternate API that will make the code in their repository more appealing to new users, that'll be good for everyone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here some points:

- Generally speaking, I agree with you on not writing your own crypto library: too many caveats, too many details to get it right. In my case, we are not talking about OpenSSL, just a small piece of a protocol which USES crypto functions (namely MAC) and it's fairly short.

- In no way my code is inteded as a replacement of the OAuth lib. Maybe, if it were more documented, it'd be easier to use and more wide spread.

- About one liners: I think that the {}[] is far more readable than having the same code as an if split in two or more lines.