# Signing requests with python-oauth2

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0

The Github page of [python-oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) gives instructions on creating signed requests with `req = oauth.Request(...)`, which returns a dictionary that can be signed. But how do I actually send these requests?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138656/signing-requests-in-python-for-oauth

Comment: @Daenyth: It is not a duplicate of of that question. That question has custom Python code to create the signature this question is using the `python-oauth2` library.

Comment: I don't expect commenting to do much, but I'd like to rebut the "too localized" reason for close. The python-oauth2 is widely used and the docs do a great job of explaining how to build a request, but not how to send a request. Answers to this question helped me solve that problem.

Answer (score 4):

Just add this line at the end:

```
rs = urllib2.urlopen(req.to_url())
```

Where `req` is your Request object.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - it just sends the (unsigned) request to the url. I'm getting some "Bad Authentication Data" message because the request isn't signed.

Comment: Actually, the docs are missing the token parameter in Client.
Should be: client = oauth.Client(consumer, token); resp, content = client.request(URL, "GET") Btw. Why is this question closed?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the next step in the README.

**Using the Client**

```
import oauth2 as oauth

# Create your consumer with the proper key/secret.
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key="your-twitter-consumer-key", 
    secret="your-twitter-consumer-secret")

# Request token URL for Twitter.
request_token_url = "http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token"

# Create our client.
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

# The OAuth Client request works just like httplib2 for the most part.
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
print resp
print content
```

Comment: I think I am a victim of extremely poor documentation. I don't think I even need the "signing" section, as what the client does in your example seems to be enough for OAuth services.